# SugarSync API get user's info: Error 401 unauthorized

Tags: api, winhttp

I'm trying to get a request for the user's information using `WinHttp` functions. The REST API call for `SugarSync` is [referenced here](https://www.sugarsync.com/developer?ref=/dev/api/resource-ref.html).

My code is as follows:

```
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
DWORD dwStatusCode = 0;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
string data;
HINTERNET hSession = NULL, 
hConnect = NULL,
hRequest = NULL;

WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO proxyInfo;
winhttpintObj.setProxyInfo(proxyInfo);

HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(  L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", 
                                   WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
                                   WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"api.sugarsync.com",   
                                     INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);

HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, 
                                         L"GET", L"/user/<userID>", 
                                         NULL, 
                                         WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                         0, 
                                         WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

string header("Authorization: ");
header += (accessToken);
header += "\n";
wstring ws = wstring(header.begin(), header.end());
WinHttpAddRequestHeaders( hRequest, ws.c_str(), (ULONG)-1L, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD );

WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                    0,
                    WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0 );

WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL);

WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest, 
                     WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE |
                     WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                     NULL, 
                     &dwStatusCode, 
                     &dwSize, 
                     NULL );

cout << "dwStatusCode: " << dwStatusCode << endl;
```

The `accessToken` is `https://api.sugarsync.com/authorization/......`. The status code returned is `401: Authorization required`. However, I've already specified it in the header. May I know where has the problem occurred and what is the possible way to resolve it? Thank you.